# openshift won't start: "Address already in use"

Tags: http-status-code-404, openshift-online-2

I'm using openshift to evaluate/mess about with jboss's BRMS tool through their workshop they have start up on the page:

http://www.jboss.org/products/brms/get-started/#!project=brms

I have loaded it onto an openshift account I created a ruby application as per instructions.  When I click on the link from the openshift I get the dreaded 404 message.

I'm able to see the following when I look into the ruby.log on openshift.

```
[Sat May 16 05:08:49 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)  Phusion_Passenger/3.0.2
1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat May 16 05:08:51 2015] [error] [client 127.8.64.129] Attempt to serve directory: /var/lib/openshift/55570898e0b8cd993200016f/app-root/runtime/repo/public/
- - - [16/May/2015:05:08:51 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "-"
[Sat May 16 05:08:51 2015] [error] [client 127.8.64.129] Attempt to serve directory: /var/lib/openshift/55570898e0b8cd993200016f/app-root/runtime/repo/public/
- - - [16/May/2015:05:08:51 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "-"
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.8.64.129:80
80 no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
[Sat May 16 05:10:10 2015] [error] [client 127.8.64.129] Attempt to serve directory: /var/lib/openshift/55570898e0b8cd993200016f/app-root/runtime/repo/public/
10.35.151.240 - - [16/May/2015:05:10:10 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Ruby"
10.35.151.240 - - [16/May/2015:05:10:10 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Ruby"
```

I can see the line

*(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.8.64.129:80
80
no listening sockets available, shutting down*

Is there something that I should have done (or can do) to avoid this? I haven't made any changes to the product (I haven't been able to access it).  I have tried stopping and re-started as well as deleting and re-installing.

Thanks,

PS. I'm a non-techie so if a solution strikes you as too simple please let me know, I probably won't have thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

The error message "Address already in use", where the address includes a port number (:80), means what it says:  Another process is already listening on port 80.  Apparently you have a web server already running on that host, already listening on port 80, so openshift can't listen there too.

To find which process is already listening, run

```
sudo netstat -napW -A inet | grep ':80.*LISTEN'
```

Then stop the service it corresponds to.